# do something when nested async function is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

```
function hello() {
   var arr = [];
   $.get(url, function (data) {
      var items = $(data).find("item");
      $(items).each(function (idx, item) {
        arr.push(item);
      });
   });
   return arr; //undefined because nested loops are not finished processing.
}
```

How do I make sure that `arr` is populated before returning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to escape from asynchronous calls. You would need callbacks to get the result of the `GET` call.

```
function asynCall() {
    var response;
    // Ajax call will update response here later.
    return response;
}
var responseFromFun = asyncCall(); // This will be undefined or null.
```

This is how your code works now. So response will always be `undefined` or `null`.

To get the response from Ajax calls pass a callback to the function when invoking it instead of assigning a response to it.

```
function asyncCall(callBack) {
    var response;
    $.get(...) {
        response = someValueReturnedFromServer;
        callBack(response);
    }
    // There wont be a return here
}
asyncCall(function(response){
    // Do something with response now
});
```

The downside here is that if you are passing `arr` object (in your code) to some other function even that has to be changed to use callbacks !

Comment: Hey thank you. Until I ran into this problem, I guess I didn't actually understand how callbacks were constructed. Now I do! Just one more question to add. Why is it necessary to check if callback is a function like `typeof callback == 'function'` as seen in some other posts related to callbacks?

Comment: @MaximusS Its just to make sure that a function was indeed passed and not a number or anything. In above code `asyncCall("hello")` is also valid but results in error when `get` call is completed as error handling is not done.